# AMQ224108/AMQ222038 events in a 2 node HA cluster w/shared NFS v4. broker storage

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm new with Red Hat AMQ, and I'm trying to test HA policy shared-store via NFS v.4, and I'm trying to figure why I'm seeing repeating warnings like these in live node:

[image]

Dunno if there might be a correlation to these Qs which slave complains about when launched:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `AMQ224108` and `AMQ222038` log entries you're seeing probably shouldn't be logged at `WARN` level. The broker is simply alerting the user that either the address itself is full or the broker as a whole is full and instead of storing messages in memory it is paging them to disk.

Assuming you're sending messages more quickly than your consumers (if any) are consuming them then there's really nothing "wrong" here at all.

Comment: Okay, right thanks, so one message more (eg. going from 5300 msgs to 5301) makes it start paging to disk on and on, it would properly be the JVMs max memory setting thats too low for the among of messages to hold in memory. Will investigate on this as well as the relative large number of messages in some Qs :)